# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing phpmyadmin on my openshift domain

Tags: tomcat, phpmyadmin, openshift

I tried to add apache tomcat in my openshift application  from my windows pc using  [this bolg post](https://blog.openshift.com/free-apache-tomcat-hosting-in-the-cloud-for-java-applications-its-called-openshift/) but in the middle i failed. then i found [this github link](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-tomcat-quickstart) and just by 3/4 command i success fully added tomcat to openshift(i also named the application `tomcat`).
I need a mysql database too then i added mysql-5.5 and phpmyadmin-4 to the `tomcat` application cartridge.
mysql working well, as i accessed it remotely using putty. but when i go to the phpmyadmin link( look like`https://tomcat-mydomain.rhcloud.com/phpmyadmin/`) i gave the user name and password and it giving me the **SSL connection error**.

Is it possible that is happening because i added a `DIY` application.?
How can i get the access to phpmyadmin now?

---

**I noticed  when go to the login page the the connection info beside url in crome said that **the identity is verified and the connection is encrypted** but when i press the  **Go** the connection info changed into **not verified and the connection is not encrypted.**

[image: login page][image: erro]
[image: login page connection info] [image: error page connection info]

**To find out the problem i created another `jboss EWS2.0` project added mysql and php myadmin there and that phpmyadmin woked nicely and gave the access.

** i tried adding and removing several times.

**Restarted the application

**Any kind of Help Will be Highly Appreciated.**

**UPDATE :**
Till now its look like its some kind of bug in openshift.

Comment: This is a known bug at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1150688 that is currently being investigated.  Please post any information there or sign up for email updates when it is commented on.

Comment: well i am gonna report this in that link.Thanks for response i thought i did some thing wrong @developercorey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its turn out to be a problem on `openshift` . Now they have solved it and working perfectly .

Bug details :  [bugzilla](http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1150688)

According to a post in response of this problem

> Just to follow up here, a few of our openshift nodes were accidentally upgraded to the latest phpmyadmin package which has a bug that causes the https/80 issue.  They have been fixed, it sounds like your applications happened to be deployed on the bad nodes during the time they were available.  You should not see this issue now.